# Prove $||{A\vec{x}}|| \leq ||A||_{\infty}||\vec{x}||$

Tags: matrices

I want to prove $||{A\vec{x}}|| \leq ||A||_{\infty}||\vec{x}||$, where $\vec{x}\in\Bbb{R^n}$, $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, and $||A||_{\infty}\lt 1$.

I tried this: suppose $||A||_{\infty} = \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{pj}|$ where p is some $i=1,...,n$ (represent the max). Now $$||A||_{\infty}||\vec{x}|| = \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{pj}|\cdot \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2} \geq \sqrt{(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{pj}^2)(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2)} \geq \sqrt{(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{pj}x_j)²}$$ but then I don't know what to do.

Can anyone help me?

I also want to ask, is there another norm that satisfies the inequality? I mean, can we replace the Euclidean norm with some other norm in the inequality?

Answer (score 1):

Careful here! By definition
$$\|A\|_\infty := \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \|\vec{x}\|_2\le 1} \|A\vec{x}\|_2$$
so you should use this definition to show your desired inequality. But this is easy:

If $\vec{x}= \vec{0}$, there is nothing to prove. If $\vec{x}\ne \vec{0}$, then because $\frac{\vec{x}}{\|\vec{x}\|}$ has norm $1$,  by definition of the above quantity
$$\left\|A\frac{\vec{x}}{\|\vec{x}\|}\right\| \le\|A\|_\infty \implies \|A\vec{x}\| \le \|A\|_\infty\|\vec{x}\|.$$

Comment: I didn't know that definition. Do you have any source where I can check it?

Comment: @saroluh https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm